# Syntax error in graph mermaid version 9.2.0

Tags: class-diagram, mermaid

I'm trying to learn how to use mermaid to generate a class diagram but I'm facing this issue: `Syntax error in graph mermaid version 9.2.0`

[image]

The code I have added I took from the [mermaid docs](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/classDiagram.html).

Exactly the `BankAccount` class:

```
---
title: Bank example
---
classDiagram
    class BankAccount
    BankAccount : +String owner
    BankAccount : +Bigdecimal balance
    BankAccount : +deposit(amount)
    BankAccount : +withdrawal(amount)
```

Has anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: where are you testing this?

Comment: in vscode, I'm using the mermaid vscode extension

Comment: which extension in particular? maybe it doesn't support classDiagrams?

Comment: this is the extension: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoyukim.vscode-mermaid-editor)

Comment: maybe try removing the title part and see if classDiagram loads